# words contains ffi

Tags: fonts

i want to use marine traffic website as a reference so i used the following

```
\bibitem{AIS} AIS \url{https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/}.
```

The web link appear in the text just fine but when you click on it is conveted to https://www.marinetra%0ec.com/en/ !!!!!

i think it is because of ffi in traffic but i don't know what to do with it.

the used packages are

```
\documentclass{marine_2015}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
aaaaaaa \cite{AIS} aaaaaa

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{AIS} AIS \url{https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/}.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

there is a separate file for this document class
should i put it with my question ???

Comment: A ligature problem...

Comment: A minimal ***compilable*** example is needed

Comment: in many bib styles, urls are set in a monospace font, which doesn't have ligatures.  if that's not permissible, then something else must be done to prevent this.  need more information on packages being used.

Comment: That's still not compilable; it's always better to add a *compilable* example (from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`).

Comment: Having asked 8 questions before, I think you should know what a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) is and why is it necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the class file `marine_2015.cls`, but after switching to `article`, I propose that you load `\usepackage{hyperref}` and `\usepackage{url}`. I also had to remove `subfigure` since it's obsolate and conflicting `subcaption`. (I wonder if you tried to run the file you provided, and if yes, if you simply ignored the error it generates. Because ignoring errors in LaTeX is a way leading into disaster.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref,url}

\begin{document}
aaaaaaa \cite{AIS} aaaaaa

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{AIS} AIS \url{https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/} [2015-03-26].
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply and help. I added `\usepackage{hyperref,url}` as you suggested and it solves my problem but colored boxes appear about references, numbers of tables and figures and url references. how can i remove it ?

Comment: They won't be printed. If you really wanna get rid of them, it's described in the manual to hyperref.

Comment: I disabled the boxes using the following 
`\hypersetup{pdfborder = 0 0 0}`